How to create a Jira Cloud project referring to a template using RESTful API
I have a Jira Cloud project configured with some notification and issue security scheme configurations.
I want to use it as a template to create the other Jira Cloud project using REST API.
I have referred to this (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-projects/#api-rest-api-3-project-post) and my code is as follows:
url = "https://accton-group.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/"
    payload = json.dumps( {
        "assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
        "avatarId": 10324, # Use Chrome Dev Tool to find out in the src of the avatar image.
        "categoryId": categoryId,
        "description": "This project is created by referring to the ST project.",
        "issueSecurityScheme": 10002,
        "key": self.project_key,
        "leadAccountId": account_id,
        "name": self.project_name,
        "notificationScheme": 10200,
        "permissionScheme": '2ef8e4b4-aaae-4c6b-bfdd-f4606a44421a',
        "projectTemplateKey": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-simplified-basic,",
        "projectTypeKey": "software",
        # "url": "http://test.test"
    } )

    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url,
        data=payload,
        headers=auth_cloud.HEADERS,
        auth=auth_cloud.AUTH
        )
    return response

But it returns an HTTP 400 error, how can I know what to rectify and the ID of permissionScheme?
